# Refactoring. How to decouple Calls to Services and $scope values modification?

Tags: angularjs, refactoring

We are working with two models: **Weeks** and **Days**. Every Day belongs to a Week.

An we got two views: **week-detail** and **day-detail**

How could we decouple the Calls to Service and the $scope values modification?

(maybe using AngularJS Directives)

.

Week Detail View has the following template, there are listed all Days that belong to the specific Week

```
<!-- file 1: week-detail.tpl.html -->
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="day in weekdetail.days">
    <td>
      <span ng-click="toggleActive(day.id, $index)">
        {{ day.active }}
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The Controller that commands this View is the following:

```
// file 2: week-detail.controller.js
function WeekDetailCtrl ($scope, $routeParams, Week, Days, DayToggleActive) {
  this.week = Week.get({ id: $routeParams.id });
  this.days = Days.query({ id: $routeParams.id });

  // @param dayId: id to be processed by DayToggleActvive.toggleActive() service
  // @param position: $index from ng-repeat, to modify this specific DOM element
  $scope.toggleActive = function(dayId, position) {
    // call to service
    (DayToggleActive.toggleActive({ id: dayId }))
      .$promise
        .then(function(data) {
           // $scope values manipulation
           $scope.weekdetail.week = data;
           $scope.weekdetail.days[position].active = !$scope.weekdetail.days[position].active;
        });
  };
}
```

Day Detail View has the following template:

```
<!-- file 3: day-detail.tpl.html -->
<div ng-click="toggleDetailActive(daydetail.day.id)">
    {{ daydetail.day.active }}
</div>
```

The Controller that commands this View is the following:

```
// file 4: day-detail.controller.js
function DayDetailCtrl ($scope, $routeParams, Day, DayToggleActive) {
  this.day = Day.get({ id: $routeParams.id });
  this.ods = Ods.query({ id: $routeParams.id });

  // @param dayId: id to be processed by DayToggleActvive.toggleActive() service
  $scope.toggleDetailActive = function(dayId) {
    // call to same service
    (DayToggleActive.toggleActive({ id: dayId }))
      .$promise
        .then(function(data) {
          // $scope value manipulation is different in Day Detail View
          $scope.daydetail.day.active = !$scope.daydetail.day.active;
        });
  };
}
```

.

Thank you in advance for your help

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [help of Oddman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26169680/2303290), we have proceeded with an advance

We have added a Custom Directive Tag to HTML

```
<!-- file 3: day-detail.tpl.html -->
<div toggleActive="daydetail.day">
    {{ daydetail.day.active }}
</div>
```

And added the directive to module

```
// file 4: day-detail.controller.js
module.directive('toggleActive', toggleActive);

function toggleActive() {
  return {
    scope: {day: '=toggleActive'},
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs ) {
      element.bind("click", function() {
        scope.day.active = !scope.day.active;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

That looks better, but... what we need is to toggle scope.day.active after successfully call to Service, so...

```
// file 4: day-detail.controller.js
// inject DayToggleActive service dependency
module.directive('toggleActive', ['DayToggleActive', toggleActive]);

function toggleActive(DayToggleActive) {
  return {
    scope: {day: '=toggleActive'},
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs ) {
      element.bind("click", function() {
      (DayToggleActive.toggleActive({ id: scope.day.id }))
        .$promise
          .then(function(data) {
            scope.day.active = !scope.day.active;
          })
          .catch(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Previously, the reference was in controller declaration, so let's remove it

```
// file 4: day-detail.controller.js
function DayDetailCtrl ($scope, $routeParams, Day) {
...
```

**NOW**

Week Detail View can be refactored the same way

```
<!-- file 1: week-detail.tpl.html -->
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="day in weekdetail.days">
    <td>
      <span toggleDayActive="day">
        {{ day.active }}
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And Day Detail Controller will include a similar directive to which we defined for Week Detail Controller

```
// file 2: week-detail.controller.js
// inject DayToggleActive service dependency
module.directive('toggleDayActive', ['DayToggleActive', toggleDayActive]);

function toggleDayActive(DayToggleActive) {
  return {
    scope: {day: '=toggleDayActive'},
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs ) {
      element.bind("click", function() {
      (DayToggleActive.toggleActive({ id: scope.day.id }))
        .$promise
          .then(function(data) {
            scope.day.active = !scope.day.active;
            // HOW COULD WE ACCESS PREVIUSLY REFERENCED AS $scope.weekdetail.week ?
          })
          .catch(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

How could we regain access to previously referenced as $scope.weekdetail.week ?
Do we need to pass that as parameter in an way?
Is there a way to reach that $scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would setup directives for your toggling, and just pass the day or week to that. For example:

```
<div toggle-week="week"></div>
```

Then in your directive, something like:

```
module.directive('toggleWeek', function() {
    return {
        scope: {week: '=toggleWeek'},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // add your scope function here
        }
    };
});
```

You can do a similar thing for your daily toggle. Then you just can just deal with the week/day binding in your directive rather than working directly on the $scope.

Hope that helps.

Comment: there is a problem refactoring the Week View. Week View shows Days in a <table>. I applied same approach to use a directive. But in this case I can't reach the previously referenced as $scope.weekdetail.week

I have added this problem in the last two blocks of code

Comment: You could use events to let other directives know that something has changed.